# yet another burned MOSFET issue in H-bridges

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, peltier

I'm trying to get into how H-bridges could be utilised in a heating/cooling peltier module for a personal fun project;
I designed the circuitry (shown below), which BTW your feedback and suggestions regarding the whole design is much appreciated, the problem is as soon as I'm switching ON the DC source(12V@3A) I'm burning the high-side P-MOSFETs. the DMP3056L could theoretically be able to handle 3A with Id_max of (-4.3/-3.4A for Vgs of -10/-4.5V) according to the datasheet; on the other hand, with Rds of (50/70mOhm for Vgs of -10/-4.5V) and considering the 3A drain current the dissipated power should be: 3^2 * (0.05 or 0.07) = 0.45-0.63 Watts and again according to the datasheet the temp rise should be 91C/W which I doubt that could cause a significant rise in the temperature to be the reason for the burning of MOSFETs.
Am I missing something here?
Datasheets:
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP3056L.pdf
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXMN3F30FH.pdf
[image: P/N-MOSFET H-Bridge]

Comment: Have you tried starting it with gpios at 0 volts and the load disconnected. You need to think about other tests and not ask for help you minute you hit the first bump in the road. Looking at your design though you will get significant shoot-through.

Comment: For future reference, 1N4001 are too slow for flyback. But it's not like a peltier has much inductance in the first place. A totem pole is better for driving your than the pull-up/NPN setup you have (though that is useful in itself to drive the totempole if need be). You are probably experiencing shoot-through as well which tends to be a problem when newbies try to go for the deceptive simplcity of driving both the high-side and low-side MOSFETs off the same signal.

Comment: What's your switching frequency ? It's inadvisable to drive MOSFETs from anything other than a low impedance. When Q1 or Q2 switch off the gates are 'driven' by 10kohms. There is likely to be a lot of dissipation due to the slow switching time.

Comment: @Andyaka interesting point. last night I checked, it seems I got some 0.6-0.7V on both gpios when I'm booting up the microprocessor (before the gpio initialisation) which is enough to activate the both transistors...pull/down resistors might solve this...regarding that shoot-through note, I wished you've explained a bit more about your assessment...thanks for the time you put on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the fine print on DMP3056 datasheet about how RthJA of 91°C/W is measured...

> Note 5: Device mounted on FR-4 substrate PC board, 2oz copper, with thermal vias to bottom layer 1inch square copper plate.

The other FET specs 131°C/W but...

> (a) For a device surface mounted on 25mm x 25mm FR4 PCB with high coverage of single sided 1oz copper, in still air conditions.

In other words these specs count on having enough copper on the board to act as a heat sink, with heat flowing through the component leads.

Some special packages can have a low Rth because the chip is mounted directly on the metal lead frame which conducts heat to the board through the pins and solder. This is not the case here, this standard SOT-23 can't dissipate half a watt.

Solution: use a FET package that will handle the required power, if this is a one-off prototype, TO220 is ideal because it's much easier to solder on protoboard than SMDs.

Or get a ready-made h-bridge, these are quite cheap.

Or keep SOT23s but pick ones with much lower RdsON.

Note if the power supply current limits at 3A, you need a more powerful supply for a 3A peltier.

Comment: and I reckon this may be the chief reason why DMP3056 is also available in SO8 and SOT26-6 packages with multiple source and drain pins, to handle such current and heat dissipation...I appreciate your time and feedback, I learned something. as you mentioned there are various options when we get to ready-made h-bridges, however, the whole point in these personal projects for me is to learn something, which I guess I did.

Answer (score -4):

**Basically the reasons of that are:**

1. Use resistors the lower wattage than the mosfet needs.
2. Short circuit in the circuit, making the mosfet die.
3. Bad cooler or no disipation of temperature in the mosfet, it includes no disipator, no fan, no resistor.
4. Overvoltage it can exceed the temperature, and make the mosfet burns like a FIRE!, very harmfull.
5. Bad use of the mosfet, some mosfet are fragile to disconections and conections and it can stop working if you disconect some part, more if the amperage are high, 2.1A or more.
6. Use a poor multimeter to test it, poor multimeter can make cut circuit when are used in a high amperage, don't care if are supported in the multimeter.

**Solutions:**

1. Use a resistor to protect the mosfet, with a wattage capacity more higher than the potence that is required by the mosfet, in the in and out all in positive, not in gnd.
2. Use a RELAY to disconect the circuit before the cut circuit go to the mosfet.
3. I recommend a fan 12v 1a if is possibly, and a aluminium disipator, with cold special cream, for electronics.
4. Use a Voltage regulator to protect it more higher than the mosfet needs.
5. Do not disconnect any part of the circuit when are on.
6. Use a professional multimeter, designed for transistors mosfet and amplifiers, a expencive multimeter.

**My not expensive recommendation is Use a mosfet that supports the double capacity, than the current mosfet  burned, and use a better refrigeration(fan and dissipation of aluminium) for it...**

Comment: Thanks mate for your time and feedback.